# Android RatingBar doesn't work on some devices

Tags: android

I am pretty new to android. I have a RatingBar widget like the one showed below :

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="0.05"
    android:isIndicator="true" />
```

I set the rating in the code. It works fine on some devices and on some, it always shows maximum number of stars(in this case 5). But if I remove the style attribute, it shows the correct number of stars. Can somebody please help me with it?

Comment: can you put code for your style attribute for rating bar